# Switch between custom tabs on lightning record page with JavaScript

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have two custom tabs on a record page. Both contain a custom lightning web component. I'd like to switch between the two tabs with JavaScript. Is this possible?

[image: Record page with tabs, custom tabs not shown]

Comment: It doesnt look like you will be able to change anything outside your component due to locker services

Comment: @PranayJaiswal In any way, can we autoselect the particular tab on page load? maybe using the URL parameter or something else?

Comment: @rahulgawale I genuinely doubt, we moved to console apps for same reason, to get more control over tabs and subtabs

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Now that's a solution I hadn't thought of yet. It's a bit drastic for now, but might be worth it in the future. Was the move worth the work?

Comment: @rahulgawale I hoped for something like that too, but if it's possible then I haven't found it yet.

Comment: thanks, @PranayJaiswal, Kasper

Comment: If you want to have control on tabs you have to create your own component using https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tabset/example

Comment: @AnshulAgrawal thank you for the suggestion. Ii thought as much, but i was hoping someone had found a different solution.

Comment: Is there any idea raised for this?

Comment: @Sarang Not that i know of